# Selenium code hits a wall on second iteration

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to fix the errors in this code and making it better.  The first iteration of this code works but the second iteration fails.

Code:

```py
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# Setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# Set the target URL
url = "https://dhan.co/calculators/margin-calculator/"

# Set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the target URL
driver.get(url)

# List of company names
company_names = ['Aurum Proptech ', 'Bal Pharma ','Entertainment Network','Career Point','Amines & Plasticizers']

def slow_type(element, text):
    for char in text:
        element.send_keys(char)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust this sleep duration for the desired typing speed

for company_name in company_names:
    # Find the search input field
    search_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "free-solo-2-demo")
    search_input.clear()

    # Type the company name slowly
    slow_type(search_input, company_name)

    # Wait for the search results to appear
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiAutocomplete-option"))
    )

    # Click on the first suggestion
    suggestion = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiAutocomplete-option")
    suggestion.click()

    # Find the quantity input field and enter the quantity
    quantity_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "qty")
    quantity_input.clear()
    quantity_input.send_keys("1")

    # Wait for a moment to let the page update
    time.sleep(2)

    # Find and extract the leverage information
    leverage_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "int_leverage")
    leverage_value = leverage_element.text

    # Print the leverage value
    print(f"{company_name} Leverage: {leverage_value}")

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
Aurum Proptech  Leverage: 5.00 X
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-e4f1f7a6f0fe> in <cell line: 36>()
     43 
     44     # Wait for the search results to appear
---> 45     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
     46         EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiAutocomplete-option"))
     47     )
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
    103             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
    104                 break
--> 105         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    106 
    107     def until_not(self, method: Callable[[D], T], message: str = "") -> Union[T, Literal[True]]:

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Sometimes wrong leverage or 0.00x will be printed.

The html code required for the above code to work:

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="free-solo-2-demo" placeholder="Search for scrips you want to invest or trade in.." type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused css-1ixds2g" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" value="">
<input type="text" class="w-full border-[0.5px] p-2 border-[#DADADA] outline-none rounded-[6px] font-CircularBook" placeholder="Quantity" id="qty" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off">
<p class="lg:text-lg md:text-base text-sm pt-1 text-[#4B4B4B] font-CircularMedium" id="int_leverage">5.00 X</p>
```

This code is part of my project but no matter how hard I try I can't fix the error.  I think it will help me to fix the error of this code and make it very efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to get the first option. You can follow these steps instead of trying to find this part of the code.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(

    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "MuiAutocomplete-option"))

)
```

1. Fill company name. (As I see, some company names have space after their name please remove them.)
2. After the first stage. Press the scroll-down key. (This will help you to get the first scrips from options.
3. You ENTER the keypress function. (Which will directly help you to pass that wall).

After following these steps your code will work clearly.